# Existence of inner twisting preserve the $*$ action on simple roots

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups

I've been trying to learn the theory of inner and outer Galois twisting in algebraic groups.

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic 0, and let $k^s$ be a separable closure. Let $G$ be a connected semisimple group over $k$. Then it is an inner $k$-form of some $k$-quasisplit group, say $G'$. There is an isomorphism $f:G \rightarrow G'$ defined over $k^s$ such that for all $\gamma$ in the Galois group $\Gamma(k^s/k)$ of $k^s/k$, we have $f^{-1} \cdot\, ^\gamma\! f \in \text{Int}(G)$.

Choose a Borel subgroup $B$ of $G$ (resp. $B'$ of $G'$) and a maximal torus $T$ (resp. $T'$) of $B$ (resp. $B'$), all defined over $k^s$. Let $\Delta$ and $\Delta'$ be the set of simple roots of $(G,T)_{k^s}$ and $(G',T')_{k^s}$. The Galois group $\Gamma(k^s/k)$ acts on each of these via the $*$-action. In the case of $G'$, since $G'$ is quasisplit, the $*$-action is just the standard action on the character lattice. Let $\rho$ be a bijection from the set of orbits in $\Delta$ onto the set of orbits in $\Delta'$.

> **Question:** Does there exist an isomorphism $f:G \rightarrow G'$ defined over $k^s$ such that for all $\gamma \in \Gamma(k^s/k)$, we have $f^{-1} \cdot\, ^\gamma\! f \in \text{Int}(G)$, and such that the induced isomorphism $X(f)$ of based root data, when restricted to $\Delta$, coincides with $\rho$?

I basically need the Galois action to be preserved by $f$. At first I thought I could just take any inner twist $f$ and compose it with an automorphism of $G'$, but I don't think that works.

Comment: In general No, because the induced isomorphism of the based root data must induce an isomorphism of the Dynkin diagrams.

Comment: What if the group is adjoint?